# Install Liferay on glassfish 3

Tags: liferay, glassfish-3

I already have a glassfish version 3 on a server. How do i install liferay into this instance without using the liferay glassfish bundle.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Liferay WAR at [this page](http://www.liferay.com/pt/downloads/liferay-portal/additional-files). (More specifically, the WAR is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.0.6/liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225.war/download)). Do not forget to download the [Liferay dependencies](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/6.0.6/liferay-portal-dependencies-6.0.6-20110225.zip/download), too. After downloading, unzip the dependencies and copy its contents to the `lib` directory of your domain in GlassFish (`$GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/lib/`). [Do not copy it to the `$GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/lib/ext/` directory](http://www.liferay.com/pt/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/121232#_19_message_5584392). I did not get Liferay working in my GlassFish 3 because of [this problem](http://www.liferay.com/zh/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6422177) and I have too limited Internet access so I cannot download the Liferay GlassFish bundle for testing the suggested solution. Anyway, I think you can go ahead from this point :)

Comment: more information here: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/installing-liferay-for-an-enterpri-4 (or in the pdf from which this is an extract)